# What is the proper Naming Convention for Classes and Their Files in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, naming

Can you kindly tell me guys as to how should I properly name classes and their files in ASP.NET assembly? I know the basic rule that class should be named starting from the capital letter and it should be a noun. But what if I'll have several namespaces in my program and several projects? For instance, I am making a program for the zoo and I want to have classes describing different animals and I have corpA.zoo and corpB.zoo namespaces and have the classes with the same names in different namespaces but with different specifics. Won't it be way too confusing?
Should I name classes and files of the animals the following way: 1) Donkey.cs 2) Monkey.cs and 3) Lovebird.cs ? Is this will be correct? I undertand that it depends on the capabilities of the file system hosting web server but it should be logical also.

Thanks in advance! Hopefully you understood what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming conventions are essential for creating a clean and organized codebase, especially when it comes to larger projects with multiple namespaces and projects. Here are some tips for naming your classes and files in ASP.NET:

- Use a unique prefix for each project or namespace to avoid naming
  conflicts. For example, if you have two projects named "corpA" and
  "corpB", you could prefix your animal class names with "CA" or "CB"
  to distinguish them, such as "CAAnimal" and "CBAnimal".
- Use descriptive names that accurately reflect the purpose and
  functionality of the class. For example, instead of just "Donkey.cs",
  consider using "MammalDonkey.cs" or "CAWorkingDonkey.cs" to make the
  class name more descriptive and informative.
- Follow standard naming conventions for classes and files. In C#,
  classes are typically named using PascalCase, where the first letter
  of each word is capitalized. For example, "MammalDonkey" instead of
  "mammalDonkey".
- Keep file and class names consistent to avoid confusion. For example,
  if you have a class named "CAAnimal" in your "corpA" project, then
  the file should be named "CAAnimal.cs".
- Avoid using reserved keywords as class names, as this can cause
  issues when compiling the code.
- Avoid using abbreviations or acronyms in class names, as these can be
  confusing and difficult to understand for other developers who are
  not familiar with the project or domain.
- Consider using namespaces to group related classes together. For
  example, you could create a "Zoo.Animals" namespace to contain all
  animal-related classes, such as "Zoo.Animals.Mammals" and
  "Zoo.Animals.Birds".
- If you have a large number of classes in a single namespace, consider
  breaking them up into sub-namespaces for better organization and
  readability.
- Use consistent naming conventions for related entities, such as
  classes, methods, and properties. This can help make your code more
  readable and easier to understand.

Finally, make sure to choose class names that accurately describe the purpose and functionality of the class, while also keeping them concise and easy to remember.

Overall, it's important to balance descriptive naming with simplicity and consistency to create a clean and easy-to-read codebase.

I suggest you also look at some boilerplate projects:
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/

Comment: Thank you so much! Those were very clear and useful advices!